# Percona Xtradb cluster on raspberry pi

Tags: percona

I setup raspbian on my raspberry and I've tried to install percona xtradb cluster as mentioned in the percona site, but it looks like the package manager can't find suitable packages for the raspberry so here am I asking for help.
How can I install percona Xtradb Cluster on raspberry pi (armhf) ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, percona xtradb cluster for armhf is included in the ubuntu repository.